# Visitor pattern and compiler code generation, how to process assignment?

Tags: design-patterns, compilation, compiler-construction, code-generation, visitor-pattern

For code generation in my programming language I am using the visitor pattern and I'd like to find a better way to handle assignment statements.

My virtual machine is registered based and each expression node visited just PUSH a register number into a global stack so when I visit the binary expression node I perform a code like:

```
static void visit_binary_expr (gvisitor_t *self, gnode_binary_expr_t *node) {
    DECLARE_CODE();

    bool is_assignment = (node->op == TOK_OP_ASSIGN);
    if (is_assignment) {
        // assignment is right associative
        visit(node->right);
        visit(node->left);
    } else {
        // visiting binary operation from left to right
        visit(node->left);
        visit(node->right);
    }

    if (!is_assignment) {
        uint32_t r3 = ircode_register_pop(code);
        uint32_t r2 = ircode_register_pop(code);
        uint32_t r1 = ircode_register_push_temp(code);

        opcode_t op = token2opcode(node->op);
        ircode_add(code, op, r1, r2, r3);
    }
}
```

With this code I can process instructions like: a + b
Assuming variable a in register 1 and variable b in register 2 code generated will be:

```
ADD 3 1 2
```

The problem is that assignments require a different set of instructions and having only register numbers on the stack is not sufficient. For example in order to access (read) a global variable I should use a GLOAD instruction while to store (write) into a global variable I should use a GSTORE instruction.

I am currently solving the issue by storing a boolean is_assignment value into each node, so I can recursively check which instruction to generate but that requires a lot of logic distributed into every visited node and I really would like to find out a more elegant way where only the visit_binary_expr function can decide what is the best instruction to generate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because assignment is quite different from other binary operations (it has a side effect of changing a left-hand-side operand), it makes sense to process it as a completely separate operation, not related to the binary operations at all. In that case you would have something like `visit_assignment` with the second argument of the corresponding type.

Then you could avoid all the checks that are present in the current code. Also, depending on the kinds of target your language allows, the processing of assignment target can use a different set of traversal functions, a different visitor, or the same visitor with a flag that indicates that a target is being processed, not a regular expression. The decision which approach is better depends on the language and the code you need to generate.